# Table layout not working in Opera Mini

Tags: html, css, html-table, opera-mini

I have used tables in my website's mobile view. The table is displayed as it should in other browsers but not in Opera Mini. I have seen that Facebook and Twitter also use tables. But those tables are shown horizontally while tables on my site are shown vertically. How can I fix this. Please help me.

Here's the CSS

`<style type="text/css">
table{width:0px;border:0;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0;padding:0;}
table tr td{width:25%;}
</style>`

Here's the HTML

`<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
        <td>Third</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Comment: provide some codes you tried....

Answer (score 0):

may be your `<td>`'s value is more than your mobile screen. Make sure you have **disabled** `Single column view` or `Mobile View` in opera mini's **setting**. Because enabling it some times cause errors in table layout like your bug. Give your feedback in Comment.  And also try 
`td {
display : inline-block
     }`

Comment: but in single column view or in mobile view facebook and twitter table look horizontally. i have tried your suggestion. but it worked in mobile, not in google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set the width of table **0px**, change it into `100%` and see if it works or not

Comment: I have used 100% width of table. But it didn't work.